# how to print the response message in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, response, native

the api is working 
i just want to print the response to the user
i'm using Axios 
this is my code

```
      axios({
        url: 'https://b-wire.co/realEstateApi/api/v1/user/create',
        method: 'post',

        data: formdata,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8;"
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            error_message:response
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: isn't `console.log` doing the job?

Comment: you can use Alert.alert()

Comment: with `Alert` you need to import `Alert Component` of react native so you can use `Alert.alert("Title", response)`, or you can use `alert(response)` on the go

Comment: If you want to print response to user. You can pass the response to an variable of state and then retrieve from there to <Text> tag

Comment: what i exactly want is how to pass the response to a variable

Comment: i tried to do it but it didn't work (i have added it to the the code above )